# How to convert 8-Byte array to Int64/long with Ruby

Tags: ruby, typeconverter, logstash-filter

I'm looking for a way to convert an 8-Byte array to Int, in Ruby.

the equivalent to the C# method 'BitConverter.()' :

```
btArr = [00,CA,9A,3B,00,00,00,00]
long A = BitConverter.(btArr, 0);

A => 1000000000
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Can you specify the expected output

Comment: how come a bit Array contain CA as an element

Comment: is that aHex???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.pack()` method of ruby to convert array values to long refer to [this](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/pack) link for documentation regarding `pack` method

```
You can do [1,2,3,4].pack("L") //L -> Unsigned Long 
It returns a string "\x01\x00\x00\x00"
```

Comment: added an example. any help would do.